Filtering a python DataFrame based on whether two column values in each row are found within a dictionary
I have a df that contains a subject ID and an item ID. An item ID may appear multiple times for one subject ID and multiple item IDs may be assigned to one subject ID.
  subid itemid
0 0001  1111
1 0001  1112
2 0001  1113
3 0001  1113
4 0002  1114
5 0002  1114

I also have a dictionary where each key is a subject ID and each value is all the item IDs that have been assigned to that subject.
dict = {'0001': ('1111', '1112'), '0002': ('1114')}

Edit: Corrected dictionary syntax
I want to iterate through each row of the df and check a) whether the subid if found in the dictionary and b) if yes, whether the itemid is assigned to that subid in the dictionary. If the answer to either question is no, I want to remove that row from the df. In the above example, I'd want rows 2 and 3 removed because 0001: '1113' does not appear in the dictionary.
I know I'm way off on this. I started by trying to create a for loop using either df.iterrows() or df.index. I don't know if this is the right way to go about it, or where to go next. I get the "unhasable type: 'Series'" error for the code below. Any help is appreciated.
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df['subid'] in dict:
        if df['itemid'] in dict:
            continue
        else:
            df.drop(index, inplace=True)
    else:
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)


is this pandas?  or polars?

Correcting the Dictionary to correct syntax then a simple function can be applied:
d = {'0001': ('1111', '1112'), '0002': '1114'}

def func(row):
    if row['subid'] in d.keys():
        if row['itemid'] in d[row['subid']]:
            return True
    return False

df2 = df[df.apply(func, axis = 1)]

print(df2)

gives
  subid itemid
0  0001   1111
1  0001   1112
4  0002   1114
5  0002   1114


iterrows is tempting for the ones that are new to pandas, but, most of the time, it is crap. To survive in pandas, you only need to 2 things: df.loc and df.apply. Everything can be done with them. Pandas offers, of course, a lot more, but you can always fall back to df.loc/df.apply.
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "subid": ["0001", "0001", "0001", "0001", "0002", "0002", "xxxx"],
    "itemid": ["1111", "1112", "1113", "1113", "1114", "1114", "pppp"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
d = {"0001": ("1111", "1112"), "0002": ("1114",)}

df["mapped"] = df.subid.apply(lambda q: d.get(q, ()))
dfresults = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x.itemid in x.mapped, axis=1)].drop(
    columns=["mapped"]
)
print(dfresults)
   subid itemid
0  0001   1111
1  0001   1112
4  0002   1114
5  0002   1114


OP should note that the Dictionary in the question is not correct Python, as corrected in this answer.

Answer will fail if a subid is not in the dictionary because .map will produce NaN and the lambda will fail with 'float' is not iterable

@user19077881 Well, then let's add an empty tuple :) I have just edited the answer.

Thank you! This worked. I had to convert the 'itemid' column in df to string data type, but it worked perfect.
